# How to print a pdf file in Emacs

Tags: pdf, emacs, printing

I use Emacs DocView mode reading pdf files, but I could not figure out how can I print the pdf file in Emacs?

I mean to print the pdf file with a physical printer, not to save a file into pdf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `M-x lpr-buffer`.